# Does EF create an in memory model of the database every time I create a new DbContext?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have the following class to create my dbcontext:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext()
        : base(nameOrConnectionString: "Default") { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
    public DbSet<TestAccount> TestAccounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }
}
```

My database has the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestAccount] (
    [TestAccountId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationId] INT,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [DataVersion] ROWVERSION,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TestAccount] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TestAccountId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT fk_AccountApplication FOREIGN KEY (ApplicationId) REFERENCES Application(ApplicationId)
);
```

From what I understand EF will create an in memory model of the database but what I don't understand is will that information automatically include the foreign key relationships or do I need to specify those like this example that I found on the internet:

```
//        public AccountConfiguration()
//        {
//            //            // Account has 1 Speaker, Speaker has many Account records
//            //            HasRequired(s => s.Speaker)
//            //               .WithMany(p => p.SpeakerAccounts)
//            //               .HasForeignKey(s => s.SpeakerId);
//        }
```

Also if the database is already existing do I need to put in things like I have to remove the PluralizingTableNameConvention?

One more question. How often does EF create the "in memory model of the database". Does this happen every time I instantiate the DbContext class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes you need to configure relationships unless you are following the conventions  . [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962)  is some details on code first conventions.
2. If database already existing you may need to change configuration(mapping) according to  the existing database.
3. For each instance of DbContext it will create an in memory instance (But it will not load all the data in the db to the memory unless you access them)

Comment: Okay so if I understand you correctly. Can I confirm if there is already a database then I would still need to use the fluent API to tell EF about things like Foreign Key relationships.

Comment: Not always.. If you have followed conventions then you don't need to configure mapping. Example - You may not need to configure SpeakerId because you are following the convention here.